# Creating Dialog Trees in Unity with Python?

Tags: unity, c#, python

I was thinking to create dialog trees with Python in Unity. I was curious if I will using in one project c# scripts and python will not cause problems with compiling scripts. Also I did found few articles about adding Python to unity, but I am not 100% sure if they are actual and they didn't been really detailed enough. Right now I am using the newest version of unity and vs 2017. I already install PythonIron, but also the newest version of it (I lazily just follow where download page leads me).

I was wondering if somebody could enlighten me with how to actually add Python to Unity and how does it work with other scripts (for example, could I have a function in c# script which could be coming from python script?)

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: I just found this thread about integrating Python on Unity's forum, but in general I would say "don't" https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/python-interpreter-in-unity.86461/

Comment: @jhocking is there any reason why I shouldn't do it? Could it work badly or there is some different reason? Also, I have seen this post, but it doesn't really explain how to do it. Or at least I am not able to figured this out.

Comment: It's not so much that it could work badly (although frankly it could) but more that this is a really difficult and not-supported way to do something that wouldn't be an improvement over programming it with C#.

Comment: So basically is better just to figured out different way with use of c# in unity. What about Unreal and connecting Python with c++? I am asking just from curiosity. @jhocking

Comment: I know essentially nothing about Unreal. I think you should use C# in Unity but I'm a touch biased :P https://www.amazon.com/Unity-Action-Multiplatform-Game-Development/dp/161729232X

Answer (score 1):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2009/10/25/running-ironpython-scripts-from-a-c-4-0-program/

The websites shows how to run IronPython Script in Visual Studio. It looks promising, although after consideration I do not think that creating Dialog Trees in Unity with Python is the best idea any more.